# What is breaking my sql program? Incorrect syntax near (

Tags: sql, sql-server

This code section

```
CREATE TABLE AIRPORT (
    Airport_Code int NOT NULL,
    City varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    State varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_AIRPORT PRIMARY KEY (Airport_Code)
)
```

Is almost the same as this one but this one is giving me an error and I can't figure out how to fix it

```
CREATE TABLE AIRPLANE_TYPE (
    Company varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Typename varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Max_seats int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_AIRPLANE_TYPE (Typename) //error is here (Typename)
)
```

I am getting the error Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: You're using either MySQL or SQL Server. They're separate products (the first is owned by Oracle, the second by Microsoft). They are not the same thing, and have distinctly different syntax. Please use the tags that are actually appropriate to your question, and don't just grab any that seem to be vaguely familiar or containing words you recognize. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Adding the primary key inline with the column will give you a crap auto-generated name for your primary key.  I also don't understand how "encouraging primary keys to be on one column" is an added benefit.

```
CREATE TABLE AIRPLANE_TYPE (
    Company varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Typename varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Max_seats int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_AIRPLANE_TYPE PRIMARY KEY (Typename)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `PRIMARY KEY`.  I have a preference for putting this directly in the column definition:

```
CREATE TABLE AIRPLANE_TYPE (
    Company varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    Typename varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Max_seats int NOT NULL
);
```

In addition to a shorter definition, this encourages all primary keys to be only one column -- an added benefit.

Comment: But then you have to code differently when you do want a composite key (just because a single column might be deemed better, does not mean it is always possible). Also this means the system names your constraint, which can make maintenance a nightmare.